# (C#) Problem with SerializedProperty. FindPropertyRelative returning null in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I am struggling to create a custom editor in Unity.
However, I am currently experiencing a problem that I cannot access other member variables inside the TalkerCharacter type variable found through the FindPropertyRelative function.
Below is some of the code I wrote.
In the Debug.Log part, "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error occurs.
I apologize for my weak English skills. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TalkerMessage : ScriptableObject
{
    public TalkerScript[] scripts;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TalkerScript
{
    public string text = "123";
    [Space(30)]
    public TalkerCharacter character = new TalkerCharacter();
    public string face = "";

    public TalkerScript(TalkerCharacter chr, string txt)
    {
        this.character = chr;
        this.text = txt;
    }
}
```

```
[Serializable]
public class TalkerCharacter : ScriptableObject
{
    public new string name = "";
    public TalkerFace[] faces = new TalkerFace[10];
    //public enum FACE { Normal, Smile, Etc1, Etc2, Etc3, Etc4, Etc5 , Etc6 , Etc7 , Etc8 , Etc9, Etc10 }
    //public Tuple<string, Sprite>[] faces = new Tuple<string, Sprite>[20];
    //public Sprite[] illust = new Sprite[System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(FACE)).Length];
    //public string dict = "";
    public TalkerCharacter()
    {
        name = "";
        faces = new TalkerFace[10];
    }
}
```

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(TalkerMessage))]
[System.Serializable]
public class TalkerMessageEditor : Editor 
{
    private Vector2 scrollPos = Vector2.zero;
    [SerializeField]
    private TalkerCharacter character;
    TalkerMessage other;
    SerializedProperty m_script;
    private ReorderableList scriptList;
    
    void OnEnable()
    {
        other = target as TalkerMessage;
        m_script = serializedObject.FindProperty("scripts");
        scriptList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, m_script, true, true, true, true);

        scriptList.elementHeight = 60 + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
        scriptList.drawElementCallback = (Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused) =>
        {
            SerializedProperty element = scriptList.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
            if (element != null)
            {
                rect.y += 2;
                SerializedProperty prop = element.FindPropertyRelative("character");
                Debug.Log(prop.FindPropertyRelative("name").ToString());
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight, 60, 60), element.FindPropertyRelative("face"), GUIContent.none);
                EditorGUI.TextArea(new Rect(rect.x + 60, rect.y + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight, EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth - 260, 60), "12321");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In this code, the serialized version of the character variable found with FindPropertyRelative shows up as non-null when printed to Debug.Log, but when I try to use FindPropertyRelative once more with this variable to access any other variable within it, an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your further nested elements of `TalkerCharacter` are all `ScriptableObject` assets and not normal serialized classes such as the `TalkerScript`.

=> For those the `prop` actually only contains an `objectReferenceValue`.

In order to dive deeper into that one you need to create a temporary `SerailizedObject` of it again like e.g.

```
SerializedProperty element = scriptList.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

rect.y += 2;
var prop = element.FindPropertyRelative("character");
if(prop.objectReferenceValue)
{
    var so = new SerializedObject(prop.objectReferenceValue);   
    Debug.Log(so.FindProperty("name").stringValue);
    EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight, 60, 60), element.FindPropertyRelative("face"), GUIContent.none);
    EditorGUI.TextArea(new Rect(rect.x + 60, rect.y + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight, EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth - 260, 60), "12321");
}
```

In general I would avoid to hide/shadow the built-in `UnityEngine.Object.name` property. Rather use a different field name like `characterName` **or** don't use a custom field at all but simply stick to the built-in one. It equals at the same time the actual asset name so actually it is quite handy to just stick to that and name your characters directly already on the `ScriptableObject` name itself.